# Safe Number of Images on an HTML Page

Tags: html, image

I couldn't find much on this, but what is a safe number of images on an HTML page?

I know for one thing that the more HTTP requests, the longer the page takes to load, but also taking HTTP requests into account how many is a 'safe' amount?

I came across this in a PHP loop that outputted many images, and after about 350, my browser crashed (Firefox).

So, overall what is a safe number of images on a page so a browser won't crash, what is a safe number so the page loads quick enough, and even with things like Data URIs, what is the limit? And also, does browser, OS, memory, size of file, and image file format make a difference?

Comment: Too broad question. I'm assuming you want to add many pictures into website for some reason. Can you specify your need? Maybe there's better solution than many images...  Browser, OS, memory, etc - it all matters. Imagine loading 100 different images (lets say all over 1MB) on a very old smartphone, and the same on newest desktop computer.